# Spring MVC - No Hibernate Session bound to thread

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have problem with session in hibernate:

```
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
2013-09-10 16:23:11 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
 INFO: Server startup in 4000 ms
2013-09-10 16:23:13 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/portal] threw          exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here] with root cause
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:687)
    at com.myportal.portal.model.HibernateDao.getSessionFactory(HibernateDao.java:31)
    at com.myportal.portal.model.HibernateDao.testowa(HibernateDao.java:46)
    at com.myportal.portal.controllers.HomeController.home(HomeController.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
```

I've read something about this problem but the solutions don't work in my case.

My Dao class:

```
package com.myportal.portal.model;
import org.hibernate.classic.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import com.myportal.portal.entity.User;

@Repository
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
public class HibernateDao {
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;


    public HibernateDao()
    {

    }
    public HibernateDao(SessionFactory sessionFactory)
    {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }
    private Session getSessionFactory()
    {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    private void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory)
    {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    public void testowa()
    {
        User u = new User();
        //SessionFactory sf = getSessionFactory();
        //Session s = sf.openSession().beginTransaction()

        // problem with this
        Session session = getSessionFactory();
        //session.save(u);

    }
}
```

root-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->


<context:annotation-config/>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/hibernate1"/>
    <property name="username" value="root2"/>
    <property name="password" value=""/>
    <property name="initialSize" value="5"/>
    <property name="maxActive" value="10"/>
</bean>    

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
   <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
   <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.spoleczniak.projekt.model"/>
   <property name="hibernateProperties">
       <props>
           <prop key="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect</prop>
           <prop key="show_sql">true</prop>
       </props>
   </property>
</bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

     <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

</beans>
```

servlet-context.xml

```
    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />
    <context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.myportal.portal" />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>
```

I use it like this:

```
@Controller
public class RegisterController {

    @Autowired
    private HibernateDao hibernateDao;

    @RequestMapping(value="/register")
    public String registerForm()
    {
        hibernateDao.testowa();
        return "register";
    }
}
```

How can I fix it?

I change DAO and create UserService, but error still appears :

DAO:

```
@Repository
public class HibernateDao {
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;


    public HibernateDao()
    {

    }
    public HibernateDao(SessionFactory sessionFactory)
    {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }
    private Session getSessionFactory()
    {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    private void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory)
    {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    public void testowa()
    {
        User u = new User();
        //SessionFactory sf = getSessionFactory();
        //Session s = sf.openSession().beginTransaction()

        // problem with this
        Session session = getSessionFactory();
        //session.save(u);

    }
}
```

UserService:

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private HibernateDao hibernateDao;


    @Transactional
    public void addContact() 
    {
        hibernateDao.testowa(); 
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class RegisterController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/register")
    public String registerForm()
    {
        userService.addContact();
        return "register";
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks you posted the same content for servlet-context.xml as you did for root-context.xml. That was a mistake, correct?

Comment: Sorry, I made mistake in this post.I corrected post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What's happening is your `servlet-context.xml` is overwriting beans in your `root-context.xml` because it's declaring a `component-scan` for the package containing the `@Repository` class. In `servlet-context.xml`, you have

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.myportal.portal" />
```

while your `HibernateDao` class is in `com.myportal.portal.model`. This `ApplicationContext` will create a `HibernateDao` bean **without transaction management**, since it doesnt have `<tx:annotation-driven>`. The `HibernateDao` bean that is autowired in your `@Controller` is this one, not the one from the `root-context.xml` (which has transaction management).

To fix this, you will want to start by adding

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.myportal.portal.model" />
```

to your `root-context.xml` and removing `<context:annotation-config/>` (it is redundant). You then want to modify the `component-scan` in the `servlet-context.xml` to something more specific that doesn't contain the package of the `@Repository` classes

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.myportal.portal.controllers" />
```

that package would contain your `@Controller` classes. You also don't need the `<context:annotation-config>`.

Comment: Ok, I changed it.Now I have problem with creating been: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateDao' defined in file [I:\Spring\vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.8.1.RELEASE\base-instance\wtpwebapps\portalSpol\WEB-INF\classes\com\myportal\portal\model\HibernateDao.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/objectweb/asm/util/TraceClassVisitor

Comment: I added asm and cglib dependency and this error disappeared. Now I have:No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/portal/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'. So I think that <context:component-scan base-package="com.myportal.portal.controllers" /> doesn't see my controllers (controllers are in this package). before modification it worked fine.

Comment: ok, now it works fine. Thanks for your help, your advices are helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here
```

This means that there is no current transaction within that thread.

As you corrected me the class is annotated with @Transactional but I see that it does not implement an interface. It may happen that the generated proxy does not expose the annotation as happens when you annotate a controller without it implementing an interface.

[See why CGLIB proxies do not retain certain annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706751/retain-annotations-on-cglib-proxies).

Comment: Oh right, did not read the code fully. But I now checked that the DAO object is not implementing an interface. Maybe the proxy generated does not expose the annotation in runtime.

Comment: The initialization step would have complained if CGLIB was missing from classpath.

Comment: It's not like CGLIB is not there, but that CGLIB creates subclasses to make proxies and subclasses do not retain annotations if you did not annotated the annotation with @Inherited

Comment: The proxy doesn't need to have the annotation, it's built because of the annotation. The proxy just has the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

During beans instantiation `servlet-context.xml` is read and beans with `@Controller`, `@Service`, `@Repository` are instantiated.

Now when `application-context.xml` (which has `<tx:annotation-driven />`) is read the beans are already there and so doesn't get transactional behavior. Make the package in `servlet-context.xml` specific to UI like controller/ Or exclude the Service, Repository package from component-scan.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.java.controllers"/>
```